# How to exit animation mode when using physics

Tags: animation, 3d-view, physics

This is a very basic question. I'm using tutorials to learn how to use physics in Blender. I made a cube and lifted it above a plane and clicked Alt-A to run the animation and let the cube fall.

How do I exit the animation so that the cube reapers back in its position in the air? (right now it's on the plane where it fell.

Answer (score 5):

You can go back to the first frame of your animation to return objects and physics to their starting states and positions.  Click the [image] button or press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Down Arrow</kbd> while the animation is paused.

[image]

To pause playback, press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, or toggle play/pause with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

Comment: You have to pause it first, this just jumps to the first frame. So you would use `Alt + A` to pause before jumping back to the first frame.

Comment: Right, Alt-A again to pause, then jump back to the first frame.

Comment: Interesting, I never knew about Ctrl+Shift+Down. IMHO using Shift+Left is easier though.

Comment: I added the Esc/Alt+A to be more complete, thanks to @iKlsR.

Answer (score 2):

You can stop animations and simulations in Blender by pressing escape <kbd>Esc</kbd>. You can pause/resume them with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>.